# Asp.net: Login redirect failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Once customer entered username and password, they need to choose radio button to login as end user or accountant. But when i click end user radio button its redirecting to main page again but not into the company.aspx page. Kindly help-

My code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from Registration where USERNAME='" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPasswordQuery = "Select password from Registration where USERNAME='" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        if (password == TextBoxPassword.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = TextBoxUsername.Text;
            Response.Write("Password is correct");

            if (EndUserRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Company.aspx");
            }
            else if (AccountantRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                Response.Redirect("AccountantUploads.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Password is not correct");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Username is not correct");
    }
}

protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EndUserRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Company.aspx");
    }
    else if (AccountantRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AccountantUploads.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check a code behind in Company.aspx/AccountantUploads.aspx pages to make sure there is a login session check after successful login, perhaps that session is null or empty and the page redirects back to home page.

Comment: sorry how do i do that?

Comment: Can you post a code behind of Company.aspx page (Page_Load event)?

Comment: Can you post your authentication section in web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

code behind company.aspx:

public partial class Company : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string _ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            Label_welcome.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");


    }



    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx");
    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string qry1 = "SELECT [USERNAME], [EMAIL], [PASSWORD], [STATE], [NAME], [CNAME], [ADDRESS], [TELEPHONE], [FAX], [TYPE], [AGENT] FROM [Registration] WHERE ([USERNAME] LIKE '%' + @USERNAME + '%')";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry1, conn);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(qry1, conn);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", TextBoxSearch.Text);
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSourceID = string.Empty;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }

    protected void GridView1_OnRowSelected(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        var username = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
        Response.Redirect("ViewUploads.aspx?USERNAME=" +username);

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your source code and analyze why Session["New"] is null?

Answer (score 0):

To manually log a user in when you're using Forms Authentication. use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie().

Example:

```
username=txtUserName.text;
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Response.Redirect just sends a HTTP redirect to the client.

Also use paramaterised queries.

```
string checkPasswordQuery = "Select password from Registration where USERNAME=@userName";
SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
passComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName",txtUserName.Text);
```

This avoids SQl injection